# Drupal Responsive HTML5 Video Background in DIV Modernizr

Tags: css, html, video, drupal, modernizr

I am trying to implement http://jsfiddle.net/mgmilcher/8R7Xx/sho/ Responsive HTML5 Video Background in my Drupal Site Homepage but have been unsuccessful. By copying all the html code over locally to my page--front.tpl.php page, the video and text appears, but obviously not how I would like. Once I add the CSS to my style.css sheet, everything disappears. I have added the JS locally to the site and currently have it in the "theme.info" file with scripts [] = 'name.js'. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have have any effect on the outcome. My theme is based on bootstrap which is the same this example has been created with.

Has anyone implemented this example into their Drupal site successfully? I would like a a responsive background video for only the main content where I can add other content - Text, over the video, and need to be able to have scroll capability to view content below viewport.

```
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="headline">
                    <h1>Welcome to our Company</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
  display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
}
.video-container .title-container {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .description .inner {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The JS

```
/** Document Ready Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Resive video
    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        videoWidth,
        videoHeight;

    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
            windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

        if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
            videoWidth = windowWidth;
            videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
        } else {
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
        }

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');


    });
}
```

I have installed the modernize module and also included the modernizr.min.js in my sites/all/libraries/modernizr folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but have you ensured that extra js files are stored inside of `sites/all/themes/THEME_NAME/js`

as Drupal doesn't run the custom js unless it's stored there for each theme that it's needed on.

Answer (score 0):

At least, you have to wrap you javascript with a jquery namespace, like this:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('input.myCustomBehavior', context).once('myCustomBehavior', function () {
       // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
      });
     }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The 'Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior' and other extra code is there because of ajax considerations.

See the doc [The Drupal JavaScript API](https://www.drupal.org/node/304258) for more info.